# Pandas: Trying to drop rows based on for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, filter

I have a dataframe consisting of multiple columns and then two of the columns, x and y, that are both filled with numbers ranging from 1 to 3.I want to drop all rows where the number in x is less than in the number in y. For example, if in one row x = 1 and y = 3 I want to drop that entire row. This is the code I've written so far:

```
for num1 in df.x:
    for num2 in df.y:
        if (num1< num2):
            df.drop(df.iloc[num1], inplace = True)
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
labels ['new' 'active' 1 '1'] not contained in axis
```

Anyhelp is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a small reproducible data set (in text/CSV/Python code form) and your desired data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid loops in your scenario, and just use `.drop`:

```
df.drop(df[df['x'] < df['y']].index, inplace=True)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(0,4,5), 'y':np.random.randint(0,4,5)})

>>> df
   x  y
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  3  1
3  2  1
4  1  3

df.drop(df[df['x'] < df['y']].index, inplace = True)

>>> df
   x  y
1  2  1
2  3  1
3  2  1
```

[EDIT]: Or, more simply, without using drop:

```
df=df[~(df['x'] < df['y'])]
```

Comment: But why not filter only? I think drop here is not necessary.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I was just going by the OP's general method, but you could just do `df[~(df['x'] < df['y'])]`, would achieve the same (or one of the other filtering methods outlined in other answers)

Comment: hmmm, I think `drop` is overcomplicated solution, `~` with `<` better, but best `>=` conditions.

Comment: @jezrael, I just timed the 4 methods with a large random `df` (`drop`, filter with `~`, filter with `>=`, and `query`), `drop` and `query` were both quite slow, whereas filter with `~` and with `>=` were close to each other, with the `>=` being marginally faster (so you're right). Keyword is "marginally" (on the order of 10e-4 seconds faster on average)

Comment: @sacul - Yes, it is here slowier, because call more functions :)

Answer (score 1):

Writing two for loops is very ineffecient, instead you can

just compare the two columns

```
[df['x'] >= df['y']]
```

These returns a boolean array which you can use to filter the dataframe

```
df[df['x'] >= df['y']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think better is use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with changing condition to `>=`:

```
df[df['x'] >= df['y']]
```

Or:

```
df = df.query('x >= y')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,2], 'y':[0,4,5,1]})
print (df)
   x  y
0  1  0
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  2  1

df = df[df['x'] >= df['y']]
print (df)
   x  y
0  1  0
3  2  1
```